# Revert transport in Hana

Tags: hana

I have moved my changes via transport to Hana stage enviroment and it ended up with errors. I want to know if there is an option to undo the transport and reimport again with fixes.

Redeploying / regenerated views and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There is no “in-import” feature but for every object that has been stored in the repository and activated it’s possible to revert to a prior version and activate manually.